# Python: storing big data structures

Tags: python, data-structures, pickle

I'm currently doing a project in python that uses dictionaries that are relatively big (around 800 MB). I tried to store one of this dictionaries by using pickle, but got an MemoryError.

What is the proper way to save this kind of files in python? Should I use a database?

Comment: It depends on what you're storing in those dictionaries. Perhaps the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) is an alternative that you can try easily (`import json; json.dumps(mydict)` and see if you get the same error).

Comment: Just dump the data onto a csv file. I have successfully done that for files as large as 3GB

Comment: Are you saying you have dictionary value fields that are individually 800-MB or that the sum of all the values is 800-MB?

Comment: user590028 - I mean the whole structure, the sum of all values, is 800 MB.

Comment: Tim Pietzcker - I like that idea, but I think it won't work since the values contain a list of frozensets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python-standard [shelve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) module provides dict-like interface for persistent objects. It works with many database backends and is not limited by RAM. The advantage of using `shelve` over direct work with databases is that most of your existing code remains as it was. This comes at the cost of speed (compared to in-RAM dicts) and at the cost of flexibility (compared to working directly with databases).

Comment: I have used shelve since it took minimal code modification. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

As opposed to `shelf`, `klepto` doesn't need to store the entire dict in a single file (using a single file is very slow for read-write when you only need one entry).  Also, as opposed to `shelf`, `klepto` can store almost any type of python object you can put in a dictionary (you can store functions, lambdas, class instances, sockets, multiprocessing queues, whatever).

`klepto` provides a dictionary abstraction for writing to a database, including treating your filesystem as a database (i.e. writing the entire dictionary to a single file, or writing each entry to it's own file).  For large data, I often choose to represent the dictionary as a directory on my filesystem, and have each entry be a file.  `klepto` also offers a variety of caching algorithms (like `mru`, `lru`, `lfu`, etc) to help you manage your in-memory cache, and will use the algorithm do the dump and load to the archive backend for you.

```
>>> from klepto.archives import dir_archive
>>> d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':map, 'd':None}
>>> # map a dict to a filesystem directory
>>> demo = dir_archive('demo', d, serialized=True) 
>>> demo['a']
1
>>> demo['c']
<built-in function map>
>>> demo          
dir_archive('demo', {'a': 1, 'c': <built-in function map>, 'b': 2, 'd': None}, cached=True)
>>> # is set to cache to memory, so use 'dump' to dump to the filesystem 
>>> demo.dump()
>>> del demo
>>> 
>>> demo = dir_archive('demo', {}, serialized=True)
>>> demo
dir_archive('demo', {}, cached=True)
>>> # demo is empty, load from disk
>>> demo.load()
>>> demo
dir_archive('demo', {'a': 1, 'c': <built-in function map>, 'b': 2, 'd': None}, cached=True)
>>> demo['c']
<built-in function map>
>>>
```

`klepto` also provides the use of memory-mapped file backends, for fast read-write. There are other flags such as `compression` that can be used to further customize how your data is stored. It's equally easy (the same exact interface) to use a (MySQL, etc) database as a backend instead of your filesystem.  You can use the flag `cached=False` to turn off memory caching completely, and directly read and write to and from disk or database.

```
>>> from klepto.archives import dir_archive
>>> # does not hold entries in memory, each entry will be stored on disk
>>> demo = dir_archive('demo', {}, serialized=True, cached=False)
>>> demo['a'] = 10
>>> demo['b'] = 20
>>> demo['c'] = min
>>> demo['d'] = [1,2,3]
```

Get `klepto` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use sqlite3? Unless you have a real old version of Python, it ought to be available: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

I have not checked the limitations of sqlite3, and I have no knowledge of its usefulness in your situation, but it would be worth checking out.

Comment: I thought about it, but would need to modify the code quite a bit. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

When you pickle the entire data structure, you are limited by system RAM.  You can, however, do it in chunks.

`streaming-pickle` looks like a solution for pickling file-like objects larger than memory on board.

https://gist.github.com/hardbyte/5955010

Answer (score -1):

Since it is a dictionary, you can convert it to a list of key value pairs (`[(k, v)]`). You can then serialize each tuple into a string with whatever technology you'd like (like pickle), and store them onto a file line by line. This way, parallelizing processes, checking the file's content etc. is also easier.

There are libraries that allows you to stream with single objects, but IMO it just makes it more complicated. Just storing it line by line removes so much headache.

Comment: I think this is overcomplicated when shelve does this already.

Comment: Storing stuff line by line doesn't seem that overcomplicated to me.. If you use shelve you are tied to shelve. If you store a JSON line by line for example, it can be read by almost any technology like Pig, Hive. Also DBM files aren't the best when the data becomes really large and you don't need random access. Line by line files are easy to check using tools like `head`, can be more space efficient and are harder to corrupt.