# How to store structures in python efficiently

Tags: python-2.7, memory-management, data-structures

We have large amount of structures: simple types (mostly floats and integers) that are logically grouped together. When we try to create class object for each structure it consumes significant amount of memory (much larger than the data on disk in sqlite database from where we load it). I know that class object uses dict internally to access fields and that dict uses hash-tables what has significant overhead of memory needed. But when we use tuples and lists we have few times better results but still far from what we have in sqlite database. Some numbers: objects about 3GB, lists 1GB, in sqlite database 120 MB. Basically this is it.Maybe there is some 3rd party library like numpy that is heavily optimized for such cases.

Comment: Why put all this giant amount of data to RAM? I think you could create a class which methods were accessing your SQLite database, or another one. Or you could import your data to RAM partially.

Comment: This data is used in a distributed system and timing is very important. The situation is even more complicated because data is used concurrently - producer is writing at the bottom and consumers are trying to read in new data. In some situations almost all data is deleted and producer starts to generate new data, clients are aware of this event. SQLIte is not very concurrent database and even if we use some other solution like MySQL we still have the problem of data transformation from tables into list of structures that are then split into chunks and are send to clients.

Comment: Maybe you should check Cython http://cython.org

Comment: Can you give more concrete example please since it is a large topic.

Comment: Well, Cython language is a modification of Python language. Any valid Python code is valid Cython code. You can also define C-variables to _save memory_, like here http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html#primes P.S. Also came across this while googling http://stackoverflow.com/q/25471026/7699691